# Import Updates option in WSUS is disabled

Tags: windows, windows-update

The "Import Updates..." option (available on the right click context menu on the Updates in WSUS) is disabled. The OS is Server 2016. 
TIA

Answer (score 0):

The Import Updates are disabled if your local WSUS server is replica of Upstream Server.